# Buefy vertical thumbnails carousel?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, buefy, vuejs3

When I use the `b-carousel` tag, it's working but the thumbnails are horizontal. How do I make them vertical?

This is the code:

```html
<template>
    <b-carousel :indicator-inside="false">
        <b-carousel-item v-for="(item, i) in 6" :key="i">
            <span class="image">
              <img :src="getImgUrl(i)">
            </span>
        </b-carousel-item>
        <template slot="indicators" slot-scope="props">
            <span class="al image">
                <img :src="getImgUrl(props.i)" :title="props.i">
            </span>
        </template>
    </b-carousel>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
      getImgUrl(value) {
          return `https://picsum.photos/id/43${value}/1230/500`
      }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
.is-active .al img {
    filter: grayscale(0%);
}
.al img {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
</style>
```

OUTPUT THAT I WANT:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Note:*** This solution has a disadvantage in that it relies on the CSS implementation details of `b-carousel`, but that might be acceptable for your use case:

You could use CSS to style the `b-carousel` elements:

- `.carousel` - the root container
- `.carousel-indicator` - the thumbnail container (a `flex` item)
- `.indicator-item` -  each thumbnail item

#### Two columns

[Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids) could be most helpful in this case, as we essentially want a 2-column grid. This is done by applying [`display: grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#:~:text=The%20element%20behaves%20like%20a%20block%20element%20and%20lays%20out%20its%20content%20according%20to%20the%20grid%20model.) to the root container, and [`grid-template-columns: auto 25%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) to create the main-image column and the thumbnail column:

```css
.carousel {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 25%;
  align-items: center;
}
```

#### Vertical thumbnails

[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) applies here. The thumbnail container is already using it, but it uses the default [`flex-flow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow) of `row` (horizontal). We could easily change that to `column` to make it vertical:

```css
.carousel-indicator {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

#### Thumbnail margins

The thumbnails have a [`margin-right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-right) between elements, intended to provide visual space between the horizontal images. Since we're switching it to a vertical layout, we can remove the margin:

```css
.indicator-item {
  margin-right: initial !important;
}
```

[image: Edit Vertical thumbnails in b-carousel]

Comment: can i ask is there anyway i can call the url name instead the index? if i didnt put the url in the method and the url is in variable how can i call it in template slot indicator?

Comment: can i ask is there anyway i can call the url name instead the index? if i didnt put the url in the method and the url is in variable how can i call it in template slot indicator?